# Recommended resources for learning MS Expression Blend

Tags: c#, user-interface, expression-blend

I've been designing applications using C# for some time now but I have the need to create a more custom application and Expression Blend was recommended to me.  I've downloaded the free trial but it's a little fancier than I expected.  I'm not a graphic designer and can't use photoshop to save my life, however I do have images provided by a graphic designer to use for this application.

I'm looking for some good resources for learning Blend and using it as a front end to a C# application, much like I would a regular C# forum.

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorials](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc184874.aspx) and [again](http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/articles/543834.aspx) and [again](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/expressionblendfordevelopers-vb/)

Also what about [this](http://www.google.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Expression Blend Starter Kits](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc268400.aspx) and the [Expression Blend Training videos](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136535.aspx#ExpressionBlendTrainingVideos).

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of great books out on Blend unfortunately. You really have to spend some time on it yourself to learn it. Also, check out local user group / code camp events if you have them in your area. I know near me there is always someone presenting on Blend in one way or another (myself included)

Just a point of clarification. You said you would like to use Blend as a "front end to a C# application like you would a regular C# form". You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what Blend is and what it is used for.

Blend is a WYSIWYG design tool for generating XAML documents. Blend is not a "front end" to your application. It is a tool you can use to build your fron end visually. Think of it like how you can use Dreamwever (I am dating myself here, does anyone even use Dreamweaver anymore) to build HTML pages visually. You use Blend in the exact same way, to build XAML pages.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Design .toolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/school/) is a great series of video tutorials, if you have the time to follow them through.